# What Programs Work Duing a Jak Sinclair Run

Tags: android-netrunner

Jak Sinclair has the following ability:

> When your turn begins, you may make a run. You cannot use programs during this run.

This pretty clearly prevents the use of paid abilities such as icebreaker abilities.  But what about other programs like Snitch or Au Revoir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs will still work during a Jak Sinclair run.  The key is the FAQ clarification on "Using":

> Any time an ability is optional, the player resolving the ability is “using” the ability. This includes all paid abilities and all optional conditional abilities (triggered abilities that use the word “may” or “allows”).

So any unconditional triggers on programs will still work.  Here are some examples:

- Pawn and Au Revoir work completely (their triggers are unconditional).
- Snitch doesn't work (it's ability says "may).
- Datasucker and Medium half-work: they will give you virus counters if the run succeeds but their virus counters don't do anything during the run (Datasucker's is a paid ability and Medium's ability says "allows")